# Como verificar se o user está ligado á internet(wifi e dados móveis)- Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Estou a usar o seguinte código para verificar se o user está ligado á internet:

```
   if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Sem ligação à Internet", message: "Para aceder necessita de uma ligação à internet", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()
        }
```

Quando estou ligado por wifi não tenho nenhum problema e o código funciona bem, quando estou ligado por dados móveis(3G/4G), então ai o if não está a dar certo e obtenho o erro que estou sem ligação á internet. Alguem sabe o porquê de isto estar a acontecer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenho um exemplo que eu encontrei pesquisando,que irá te ajudar,neste exemplo ele funciona com 3G e Wi-Fi.

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public class Reachability {

    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0)).takeRetainedValue()
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = 0
        if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) == 0 {
            return false
        }

        let isReachable = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0

        return isReachable && !needsConnection
    }

  if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true { <-- Seu código
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Sem ligação à Internet", message: "Para aceder necessita de uma ligação à internet", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()
        }

}
```

Baixe a classe Reachability,aqui neste [link](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) e adicione no seu projeto.

Te aconselho a dar uma olhada neste [link](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-check-for-internet-connection-in-swift/),que irá te ajudar a entender melhor.

Comment: E isso mesmo já consegui. Muito Obrigado :)